# How to get a post parameter using vertx request object?

Tags: vertex

I have a request object.

I tried doing

```
 var str;
 for (var i in this.request)
 {
      str += i + "\n";
 }
```

And got:
headers
params
response
getClass
equals
query
class
hashCode
wait
uri
pause
resume
endHandler
bodyHandler
notify
path
dataHandler
method
toString
exceptionHandler
notifyAll

Post parameters are nowhere to be found. Can anyone shed some light into this mistery ?

params() and headers() don't contain anything.

Comment: The solution is to add a dataHandler to the request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a bodyHandler (here assuming you're posting JSON):

```
req.bodyHandler(function(data) {
  var postData = JSON.parse(data.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the formAttributes on the http request. Here is an example in scala

```
  req.expectMultiPart(true) //Will expect a form
  req.endHandler({

    req.formAttributes() //This is used to access form attributes

    //some code with attributes

  })
```

Reference: http://vertx.io/core_manual_java.html#handling-multipart-form-attributes

Comment: This piece of code is throwing `Request has already been read` exception

Comment: Should only happen if you have already read the request. This is a helper added in vertx 2 to assist with http forms. Code taken directly from a working project. Perhaps you can open another question with your exact problem?